# What does formatResult and formatItem options do in JQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Am a bit confused here, what does the formatResult and formatItem do in the JQuery Autocomplete plugin?

I have a function that is returning a comma separated string (from Django), but my autocomplete function is unable to split the string into individual entries/rows, how can i achieve this using autocomplete functions?

e.g the returned result looks like this and this what autocomplete is showing :-
**["one","oneTwo", "Onethree", "anotherOne"]**

I want when showing in the autocomplete field to have it split like this:-

```
one
oneTwo
Onethree
anotherOne
```

I have a feeling i can use the formatResult and formatItem but i dont know how, there are no good examples out there !!

my code in the html template:

```
 function autoFill(){
           $("#tags").autocomplete("/taglookup/", {
        width: 320,
        max: 4,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: " ",
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300
         });
       }
```

Am using Dajango to process the GET request.

Gath

Comment: Feel free to ask for clarification of my answer if necessary. If it addresses your question, please award me the answer. ;o)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`formatItem` formats an item for display in the dropdown list, while `formatResult` formats the item for display in the inputbox once it is selected.

By default, autocomplete expects to get data from the specified url formatted as:

```
foo|bar|baz|bing
zaz|ding|blop|grok
```

where each line is a row of data; each row being the data that it passes to `formatItem` and `formatResult`. You may want to take the path of least resistance and return data in the way it likes.

If you want to use data that doesn't fit autocomplete's assumptions, you'll need to use the (undocumented, as far as I can tell) parse option to identify a function to parse the results of your ajax request. It appears to me that your django view is returning an array rather than returning a formatted string. To format your array as jquery would like it:

```
return HttpResponse('|'.join(your_array), mimetype='text/plain')
```

Here is an example of doing autocomplete using non-standard autocomplete data (JSON):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  format_item = function (item, position, length){ 
    return item.title; 
  } 

 // Handle data from ajax request 
 prep_data = function(data){ 
   tmp = $.evalJSON(data); 
   parsed_data = []; 
   for (i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) { 
     obj = tmp[i]; 
     // Other internal autocomplete operations expect 
     // the data to be split into associative arrays of this sort 
     parsed_data[i] = { 
        data: obj , 
        value: obj.isbn13, 
        result: obj.title 
     }; 
   } 
   return parsed_data 
 } 

 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#fop").autocomplete({ 
          url : "{% url book-search %}", 
          // undocumented 
          parse: prep_data, 
          formatItem: format_item, 
          }); 
 }) 

</script>
```

Comment: I think it would be more clear if you changed your "foo|bar|baz" example data to mirror the book-search example from the JSON section.

Comment: I think you should more clearly highlight that your answer contains 2 different approaches (split it into 2 answers?)

Comment: Perhaps you could change "Here is an example of doing autocomplete using non-standard autocomplete data (JSON)" to simply "Here is an example of autocomplete using (JSON)"

Comment: I think it would be more clearl if the "undocumented" comment was moved from above the line to the right of the line or if it read something like ("replace the undocumented parse function implementation with one that can parse JSON data")

Comment: You may want to include a pointer to http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ near the line where your parse the JSON data "$.evalJSON(data)"

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to get formatMatch and formatResult to work so far.  I am still working on the 'correct' way to use them.  However, as a workaround you can use the parse option as follows.  Just to be clear, in this example, formatItem and parse are functional while formatResult and formatMatch are not functional.

```
jQuery(function(){
   $('#profile-tabs_addresses_grid_b_a_PostalCode').autocomplete
('http://test.mydomain.com/locality/postalcodes/', {
       minChars:1,
       delay:400,
       cacheLength:100,
       matchContains:true,
       max:10,
       formatItem:function(item, index, total, query){
           return item.PostalCode + ': ' + item.Region + ', ' +
item.City + ', ' + item.Country;
       },
       formatMatch:function(item){
           return item.PostalCode;
       },
       formatResult:function(item){
           return item.PostalCode;
       },
       dataType:'json',
       parse:function(data) {
                       return $.map(data, function(item) {
                               return {
                                       data: item,
                                       value: item.PostalCode,
                                       result: item.PostalCode
                               }
                       });
               }});
});
```

here is the json data that comes back from the data url ( whitespace
added for easier viewing ):

```
[
       {City:"St. Louis", Country:"USA", PostalCode:"63103", ID:3,
Region:"Missouri"},
       {City:"St. Louis", Country:"USA", PostalCode:"63109", ID:1,
Region:"Missouri"},
       {City:"St. Louis", Country:"USA", PostalCode:"63119", ID:2,
Region:"Missouri"}
]
```

When I type a 6 in the postal code box, it shows all three options
properly formatted as:

```
63103: Missouri, St. Louis, USA
63109: Missouri, St. Louis, USA
63119: Missouri, St. Louis, USA
```

and when I select one the textbox receives just the selected 
postal code.