# jQuery UI Autocomplete formating help, (I'm new to jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've been using [this tutorial](http://1300grams.com/2009/08/17/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-jsonp-support-and-overriding-the-default-search-parameter-q/) to make an autocomplete function.  (UPDATE: I ditched the jQuery UI Autocomplete route because there isn't much documentation for it.)  The following code works (FINALLY).  I also managed to get the suggestion links to work as well.  I plan to make some type of blog post to help other noobs like myself figure it out. :)

```
$("#q").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
document.location.href = row.url;
});

$("#q").autocomplete("/a_complete.php", {
    dataType: 'json',
    parse: function(data) {
        var rows = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            rows[i] = { data:data[i], value:data[i].pos, value:data[i].team, value:data[i].url, result:data[i].value };
        }
        return rows;
    },
    formatItem: function(row, i, n) {
        return '<a href="' + row.url + '">' + row.value + ' <span style="float: right; font-size: 11px; color: gray; padding-right: 10px;"><strong style="">' + row.pos + '</strong> ' + row.team  +' </span></a>';
    },
    extraParams: {
        q: '',
        limit: '',
        sport: '<?=$sport?>',
        featureClass: 'P',
        style: 'full',
        maxRows: 15,
        term: function () { return $("#q").val() }
    },
    max: 25,
    scrollHeight: 300,
    width: 200
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been meaning to play around with the brand new autocomplete too, but havent had chance to as of yet... however have you seen this tutorial? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/. There might be something in that?

Ooo also spotted this? [What does formatResult and formatItem options do in JQuery Autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737453/what-does-formatresult-and-formatitem-options-do-in-jquery-autocomplete) from a previous poster, looks like you have to do a little bit of tweaking to get it to work, failing this you could concatenate the data into one chunk and pass it through that way?

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob.

I haven't come across that tutsplus tutorial before, it does look helpful.  My plan is to give up on it today and take a fresh look at it tomorrow morning.  My brain needs a reboot =P

If anyone else has come across anything helpful, please do post as well.  I'm sure it can help me and others as well. :)

Comment: hehe i know the feeling brant, let me know how you get on with that tuts+ tutorial, i fancy having a go myself! if i come up with anything good ill repost on here for you all to see :)

Comment: Rob!!  Good news, I've managed to get a lot further.  Though I am stuck on trying to get the turned output to actually go to the link.  Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, not sure... you could try just printing the output just to make sure what u are outputting is correct, also i'm not sure whether in your extra params: sport: '<?=$sport?>' should be sport: "<?=$sport?>" ?